# Нужно исправить ошибку с итерацией

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно создать класс итераторов, в который подаётся список и количество итераций. Итератор
выводит элементы списка со случайными индексами. Примечание: нельзя выходить за пределы
списка; понадобится функция random.choice()

Написано:

```
import random

class Interators:
    def __init__(self, collection, number_of_iterations):
        self.collection = collection
        self.number_of_iterations = number_of_iterations 

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.number_of_iterations <= len(self.collection):
            result = random.choice (self.collection)
            return result

        else:
            raise StopIteration


a = Interators([1, 2, 5, 7], 4)
for j in a:
    print(j)
```

Проблема состоит в том, что output не останавливается, а он должен рандомно распределить числа из списка 4 раза

Comment: нут так счетчик `number_of_iterations` у вас не меняется, а следовательно и условия окончания нет

Comment: как можно это оформить? просто не знаю куда и как записать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас неправильно реализован метод `__next__`.

Ошибка в условии.
Длина списка вообще не должна участвовать в расчётах (какое она имеет дело к количеству итераций?). Вы должны сравнивать `number_of_iterations` с `0`, а после генерации очередного значения уменьшать на `1`.

***Пример:***

```py
    def __next__(self):
        if self.number_of_iterations > 0:
            result = random.choice(self.collection)
            self.number_of_iterations -= 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет переменной состояния итератора. Предположу, что вы планировали сделать такого рода счетчик из `number_of_iterations`. Вот правильный код:

```
from random import choice, sample

class Iterator:
    def __init__(self, collection, iterations):
        assert iterations >= 0
        self.collection = collection
        self._cur_iteration = iterations

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self._cur_iteration:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self._cur_iteration -= 1
            return choice(self.collection)
```

Если количество итераций меньше длины коллекции, то это можно записать гораздо проще, если делегировать функциональность итератору списка (`list`):

```
class Iterable:
    def __init__(self, collection, iterations):
        self.collection = sample(collection, iterations)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.collection)
```